# Displaying multiple dependent python models on 1 page

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I'm building a web application for college students. What I'm on right now is the main screen-- users will select their department (ie CSE), class (ie CSE 101) and professor (in case there are multiple/class).

So the flow will look like this  ECON --> ECON 101 --> Professor X.

So I have 3 models, Department, Course, Professor

```
class Department(models.Model):
     subject         = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
class Course(models.Model):
     department      = models.ForeignKey(Department)
     number          = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
     name            = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = True, null = True)
class Professor(models.Model):
     course          = models.ForeignKey(Course)
     name            = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

I've built this with 3 views. My first view shows all of the departments. Based on which department the user clicks on, it will load a new page that shows all of the courses associated with that department. Then when the user clicks on a course, it loads a new page that shows all of the professors associated with that course.

```
#urls.py
url(r'^$', 'index'),

#views.py
def index(request):
    a     = Department.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('qanda/index.html', {'departments': a})

#index.html
{% for department in departments %}
    <li><a href="/home/{{ department.id }}/">{{ department.subject }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

#urls.py    
url(r'^(?P<department_id>\d+)/$', 'courses'),

#views.py
def courses(request, department_id):    
    a = Department.objects.get(pk = department_id)
    b = Course.objects.filter(department = a)
    return render_to_response('qanda/courses.html', {'department':a,'courses':b})

#courses.html
{% for course in courses %}
    <li><a href="/home/{{ department.id }}/{{ course.id }}/">{{ course.department }} {{ course.number }} {{ course.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

And so forth.

Now that it works, I want to make it look a bit nicer, so I'm user a jQuery plugin, [jGlideMenu](http://www.sonicradish.com/labs/jGlideMenu/current/static_demo.html) (see example). For the plugin to work though, I need to display all of the departments, courses, and professors on 1 HTML page. But I can't properly link deparment -> course -> professor b/c all I have currently is just the 1 for function on the page to display the list.

Is there any way around this? Maybe a better jQuery plugin? Or how do I remedy this? Let me know if not clear or I can provide any more context.

Comment: Use [django smart selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use regroup tag. For example:

```
<ul id="departments">
    {% for department in departments %}
    <li rel="department_{{ department.id }}">{{ department.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% regroup courses by departments as department_list %}

{% for department in department_list %}
    <ul id="department_{{ department.grouper.id }}">
        {% for course in department.list %}
          <li rel="course_{{ course.id }}">{{ course.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

And the same for the professors. If there are a lot of data, it's better to use ajax requests.

Comment: actually so just tried it and while I can load the first list, I can't load any of the following lists-- my understanding of grouping is you can take an existing list and regroup it by a certain attribute. but on my index page, the next list is populated based on which attribute the user clicked prior -- ie if someone clicks on Econ, then the next page will populate the list of classes related to Econ. See #views.py in the question. Does regroup still work for this?

Comment: To build full menu you should return all departments, courses and professors in the index view. `render_to_response('qanda/index.html', {'departments': Department.objects.all(), 'courses': Course.objects.all(), 'professors': Professor.objects.all()}) `